# What's a good way to say "liminal"?

Tags: translation, words, nuances

I speak a fair amount of Japanese (from America, live in Kobe, Japan), but am having a hard time finding a good way to say liminal.

The best I can think of is things like gap or transition 間 【あいだ】

Comment: Could you add some example phrases in English to clarify why usual dictionary definition doesn't work?

Comment: Please provide a few example sentences. This is important for several reasons: 1. there might be different meanings/nuances depending on how it is used, where different translations would be appropriate (even if the same word is used for all cases in English) 2: It is not a common word so people can have difficulty understanding exactly what you want to say

Comment: To think of it, **間** is a nice choice, in a sense it may be used for **顕在と潜在の間** (or 壁 or 膜) i.e. the **critical faculty** which lays **between** . E.g. *you claim to be from Kobe because you want to penetrate our **顕在と潜在意識の間にある壁** so we will watch the Lakers game.*

Comment: Welcome to the Japanese Language Stack Exchange, Leslie Betz. I initially assumed you were asking for a translation for "liminal" as it is commonly used by humanities scholars influenced by the cultural anthropologist Victor Turner; since this is not information readily available in English-Japanese dictionaries and the like, I wrote an answer that gave a few options and some usage examples. On reflection, though, I agree with sundowner and a20 that you need to clarify your question, so I have removed my answer. If it turns out that it was what you were looking for, I'll restore it.